# Use of "have to" (not as a obligations)

Tags: phrase-usage

I want to simply tell my friend about my pending works. Shall I use "have to" to express the same.

> 1. I have to go to market.
> 2. I have to mail reports.
> 3. I have to clean my room.

Here no one is forcing me to do these works. Is the use of "have to" correct.

Comment: Yes, but your examples all illustrate obligation or necessity.

Comment: You could use 'I have to' or 'I need to' if it is important to do that thing, even though no-one is forcing you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of "have to" vs "am to"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/151459/use-of-have-to-vs-am-to)

Answer (score 1):

[Merriam Webster "have to"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have%20to)

1—used to say that something is required or necessary
*I have to remember to stop at the store.*

3-—used to say that something is desired or should be done
*You really have to see the doctor about that cough.*

This dictionary draws a distinction between "necessary" and "desired". I think that the difference is one of degree; you can use "have to" in all your examples, and even in something expressing just a desire, for example, *"I have to be more careful with money."*